# Using JQuery select all items except those in an excluded class

Tags: jquery

I want to select all items that are inside an element with the class DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML

```
var all = $(".DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML *") <== This works
```

But now I want to exclude all items with the class nostrip

I have tried these:

```
var all = $(".DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML *").not(".nostrip");

var all = $(".DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML *:not(.nostrip)");

var all = $(".DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML *:not('.nostrip')");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/8HyhC/

you need to use jquery's each function to parse every element which don't have desired 
class.
Please check above link I hope you will get what you need.

```
$('.DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML').not('.reMode_selected').each(function(i,j){

alert(j.title);
});
```

let me know if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out through trial and error

```
var all = $(".DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML *").not($(".nostrip *"));
```

Comment: `.not($(".nostrip *"));` -> `.not(".nostrip *");`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to show you the `.filter()` function:

```
$('.DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML *').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).hasClass('nostrip');
});
```

I think it should work but let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if you want to do it with a single query:

```
$(".DnnModule-efforityEaloHTML *[class!=nostrip]")
```